# How are the rules of the election?

Tags: discussion, election

I am wondering how the actual election is conducted. So far the [election page](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election) does not explain the rules.

I found an [old blog posting](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/):

> Once the election begins, there will be per-user site notifications to all eligible voters. In the election phase, all community members with at least 150 reputation can cast three votes: 1st choice, 2nd choice, and 3rd choice. All votes are private until the election is complete, at which point the election data file (the vote totals for all the candidates; no identification of who voted for whom) will be freely and permanently downloadable by anyone. We will calculate the winners using OpenSTV and the Meek STV method.

Another posting suggested that these rules are kind of experimental and might change.

Is this still up to date?

Comment: Also, I think we should have @nealmcb verify that this election mechanism is secure... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sidebar of the election page has the rules for each phase.

### Nomination Tab

> In the **nomination** phase, any community member in good standing with more than **300** reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.
>
> Nominees are required to construct a small, freely editable introduction to describe why they might make a good community moderator. Comments are active during the length of the nomination phase – please comment freely, particularly if there is any way a nominee introduction can be improved or refined to be more clear.
>
> All nominees are displayed in *most recently nominated first* order.
>
> Nominations are not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion at any point during the nomination phase.
>
> After 8 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the **primary** phase. However, if there are 10 candidates or less, we skip directly to the **election** phase.

### Primary Phase

> In the **primary** phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community voting. Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in *random* order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion at any point during the nomination phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top **10** candidates based on primary vote score proceed onward to the **election** phase.

### Election Phase

> In the **election** phase, 10 candidates advance to final community voting. Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the election.
>
> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, starting with the most desirable candidate first.
>
> All candidates are displayed in *random* order.
>
> The vote tallies are private until the election is complete.
>
> After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable from this page forever, and we will calculate the winners using [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) with the [Meek STV method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I missed the changed text on that red bar because it is at the far bottom on my screen.